# Operator overloading "float" and "<<"

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

In short, i made class Fraction:

```
class Fraction
{
    int N;
    int D;
public:
    ostream& operator <<(ostream &);
    operator float();
};
```

and in function main() i have:

```
Fraction a(3, 4);
cout << a << " = " << endl;
cout << (float)a << endl;
```

as output i get:

```
0.750000 = 0.750000
```

Why operator << is unused ( it should print "( 3/4 )" ).

My operator << working correctly if i delete operator float, but i need conversion Fraction to float for some other methods and functions.
How can i use my output operator.

Wanted output:

```
( 3/4 ) = 0.750000
```

Comment: May be you can show us your `overloaded <<` definition ?

Comment: Also you should rather have something like `friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &, const Fraction&);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output `operator<<` should accept the stream as the first argument, and the fraction as the second argument. Right now, it does the opposite (the fraction is the first argument, and the stream is the second). This means the operator isn't called, instead the fraction is converted to `float` and then the float is displayed.

The operator you wrote can be called with `a << cout`, which is obviously wrong.

Instead of making it the member operator, you should implement this operator as (friend) non-member, outside of your class.

Sample signature:

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fraction& f);`

Comment: Made operator << as friend of class and it working now. 
I overloaded operator-() now, (1 argument "-"), it changes fraction to the opposite (3/4) -> (-3/4)

    cout << -a << endl;

as output i get

    -0.750000

Why now it isn't (-3/4), ( my operator-() returns fraction ), i tried overload operator<< on different ways, also tried make operator-() as friend.

Comment: @user3464829 I cannot answer this question by only the details you posted. You should post more details (the best you can do is to strip the code to the base essentials (max 40 lines), so I can simply paste it in my IDE and compile), but... you may be better off with asking another question.

Comment: As @πάντα ῥεῖ said, i made operator<< like this
`friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &, const Fraction&);`
(i miss "const") and now everything work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `operator <<` outside of your class, as a non-member (friend) function.

See [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Answer (score 0):

The `operator<<` should not be a member of your class, since it needs to have the stream object as its first argument and have signature `ostream &operator<<(ostream &, Fraction)`.

Comment: Why `Fraction` by value? That's unusual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because why not? From what I can tell, it's most probably a POD with two `float` members. There's no need to pass it by reference and stuff.